# Can't jUnit test with file from resources folder

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I'm trying to unit test with a file located under src/test/resources, but I can't always get a nullpointer when I'm trying to read it.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.2, with JDK 10 and Gradle.

I've tried many variants of code found when googeling the problem, but I have no success.

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
     ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.moc.omc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 10

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.0")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.0")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

My test is some variant of these lines (nothing I've tried has had any success):

```
@Test
public void isSortedCorrectly() throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("test-file.json").getFile()); // java.lang.NullPointerException
}
```

The test class is here:

> src\test\java\com\moc\omc\x\y\MyUnitTest.java

The test file is here:

> src\test\java\resources\test-file.json

Comment: Do you need a `File`, or can you do with an `InputStream`? Because you cannot reliably load a file via `ClassLoader.getResource`. Also, put a `/` before the file name.

Comment: I can't get it to work. It seems to be referencing `src/main/.../resources` and not `src/test/resources`. If i run this code it will give me the file in the `src/main/.../resources` folder.

Comment: @Magnus I know this is taking you way back in the Way-Back machine, but did you ever get a solution to this issue?  I am running into a similar thing right now in a Spring Boot app using Gradle 7.6.  Unit tests are not pulling in the /src/test/resources at all, so they blow up trying to load the Spring App Context because it can't find the properties file at all.  Tried adding the path manually in my build.gradle file, but so far I haven't found any combination that works.

Answer (score 3):

The file needs to be at

```
src\test\resources\test-file.json
```

Instead of

```
src\test\java\resources\test-file.json
```

Comment: Good point. It still doesn't work though. What's weird is that if i enter `File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("application.yml").getFile());` it will reference the `src/main/.../resources`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your IDE it is possible that your resource directory is not in the classpath.

In IntelliJ:

1. Right-click your test/resources (or test/java/resources) directory
2. Select the "Mark Directory as..." sub-menu
3. Select "Test Resources Root"
4. This directory will appear with a decorator graphic symbolizing that it is in the classpath

In Eclipse:

1. Go to "Run->Run configurations..." (in case of debug "Run->Debug
   configurations...")
2. Open Run (Debug) configuration which you use
3. Open "Classpath" tab
4. Select "User Entries" and click "Advanced..." on the right
5. In the opened window select "Add folder", point to your src/test/resources
6. This folder will appear under "User entries", then you should move it up to make it the first on your classpath